# AWS CLI - AutoScalingGroup name not found - null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, autoscaling

I'm trying to run the aws cli command for updating a auto scaling group and when I pass in the ASG name, the response is saying that the ASG name isn't found but it returns 'null' as a reference of what is passed in, you can find more on the documentation here: [Documentation Link](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/autoscaling/update-auto-scaling-group.html)

AWS CLI Example
`update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name "name-of-the-asg" --min-size 4 --max-size 40`

Error Response
`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateAutoScalingGroup operation: AutoScalingGroup name not found - null`

I've tried using a json file with the correct json syntax and I get the same error.

Does anyone know if this error means that the ASG name isn't being registered in the command itself or if the ASG name is passed in and not found so it returns that it's not found with a null reference?

Any clarity on what this error means and if there is a different way to make this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I left out the `--region` parameter. Once I added the correct region the AWS CLI command was able to execute successfully.