# AWS Electric Beanstalk - Service:AutoScaling, Message:AutoScalingGroup name not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to build my Elastic Beanstalk first instance for a Python application and have been following a few different guides that seemingly sail through the issues without error.

The first error I encountered was linked to [Error with not existing instance profile while trying to get a django project running on AWS Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790666/error-with-not-existing-instance-profile-while-trying-to-get-a-django-project-ru/76620598#76620598) and I seem to have solved this and moved past.

How I am getting the following error(s):

```
Creating Auto Scaling group named: ... failed. Reason: Resource creation cancelled
Failed to launch environment.
Service:AutoScaling, Message:AutoScalingGroup name not found - AutoScalingGroup ... not found
```

Currently it still seems to be trying to create/launch the environment but there are a number of Deleting messages that follow so I guess it knows its failed.

How do I overcome this?   Mostly the other people experiencing issues seem to be coming via the CLI. e.g. [AWS CLI - AutoScalingGroup name not found - null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919751/aws-cli-autoscalinggroup-name-not-found-null)

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk provisions resources using CloudFormation. Can you go in your CloudFormation console, see the stack, and view the error messages. That would be best place to check what is exactly causing the issue.

Comment: Nothing appears in the Cloudformation > Stacks page.     Do I need to create a stack before I start or does EB do that for me?

Comment: It creates one for you. Have you deleted the Elastic Beanstalk? or you might checking in wrong region.

Comment: Not deleted.  Application still exists and Environment said terminated / now vanished.   Application exists in eu-north-1.  Checking that in CF and no environment.    Do they deleted when terminated?

Comment: Terminated means deleted. It will appear there for sometime, but after that it will be removed from console.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying again and will update my question with the environment config if it fails.   Maybe you will be able to see where its going wrong.  Thank you for your help so far.  :)

Comment: That worked this time and I don't think I did anything different.  The only change was that in my previous attempt I switched on Basic Health Reporting and this time it wouldn't let me due to using a managed environment.   Any chance some changes were being migrated through?